# BeagleBone Black static IP retention

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am using BeagleBone Black device as an energy monitoring device in my IoT projects. The application reads data through USB (Modbus RTU) and sends it to remote cloud through MQTT. There are around 15–20 such BeagleBone Black devices. To access the Internet, the plant IT manager given me 15–20 instances of static IP addresses. I have set static IP address in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. But sometimes the Internet connectivity is not working. When I debugged it, I found that BeagleBone Black is getting dynamic IP address.

There are separate ranges for static and dynamic IP address in the plant. If I reboot the BeagleBone Black, it again catches the static IP address properly and the system works normally.

I am facing this issue in random IP address. As of now there is no option of shifting it permanently on the dynamic IP range. This is occurring in random devices. Please help me to resolve this issue. Here is the IP set in the `/etc/network/interface` file and the IP address received.

For example, the static IP address set in the device. This is the `/etc/network/interface` configuration file in the BeableBone Black:

```
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.12.4.152
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    gateway 10.12.4.1


# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

##connman: ethX static config
#connmanctl services
#Using the appropriate ethernet service, tell connman to setup a static IP address for that service:
#sudo connmanctl config <service> --ipv4 manual <ip_addr> <netmask> <gateway> --nameservers <dns_server>

##connman: WiFi
#
#connmanctl
#connmanctl> tether wifi off
#connmanctl> enable wifi
#connmanctl> scan wifi
#connmanctl> services
#connmanctl> agent on
#connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk
#connmanctl> quit

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# Used by: /opt/sripts/boot/autoconfigure_usb0.sh
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

IP address in the file:

> ```
> address 10.12.4.152
> netmask: 255.255.254.0
> gateway: 10.12.4.1
> ```

IP address received (checked using `ifconfig` command):

> ```
> inet 10.12.4.207  netmask 255.255.254.0
> ```

The full response of `ifconfig` command:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC> mtu 1500
        inet 10.12.4.207  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.12.5.255
        inet6 fe80::f6e1:1eff:fe8c:d785  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f4:e1:1e:8c:d7:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 146702  bytes 10983334 (10.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6716  bytes 509906 (497.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 174

lo: flags=74<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 164064  bytes 18078349 (17.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  everruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 164064  bytes 18078349 (17.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 192.168.7.3
        ether f4:e1:1e:8c:d7:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.2  netmask 255.255.255.252  braodcast 192.168.6.3
        ether f4:e1:1e:8c:d7:8a  txquequelen 1000 (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I worked with a beaglebone black, the stock Debian image for it did something did something weird and (frankly) broken by having two completely separate DHCP clients active at the same time. You seem to be using /etc/network/interfaces the other is "connman". Be very careful to ensure connman has been disabled from acting as a DHCP client or it will think it's in control and reconfigure your network.

Given the "random" nature of your problem it does sound like, *in some cases*, your network is being reconfigured by connman after it's been configured statically by /etc/network/interfaces

I see commented out commands in your screenshots which try to do this but it's unclear if you are certain this has actually been executed on every device

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Philip. Yes, the comments in the (etc/network/interfaces) file has been executed for every device. I was not aware of the 'conman' thing as i am quite new to using linux. Will read about conman and work on your suggestions. Thanks again